# Can the ctest output be colored?

Tags: ctest

Is there a way to color the ctest output.
For example is it possible to have something similar to the last line being green in case of 100% success

```
100% tests passed, 0 test failed out of x
```

or red otherwise?

Comment: [puio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14170429) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65510138) saying "https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/2577 Some colors were added in 2018"